# Looping through different files

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to loop through some files but I have a problem when trying to put an if and get some data from there.

I have a folder named Channels with 654 txt files each have 1 json with 100 json nested in an array

Also I have a list of phone numbers which I take from a csv (2500 numbers)

What I need to do it's check if a phone number from the list matches with channel from any json of the 654 text files

I made this code but the problem here its if I just put 1 phone number which matches with 8 json, it's works fine, but If I check the same phone number adding other 3 new numbers to the list, the result its completely different and only matches with just one json

```
const fs = require('fs');

let csvFormatPhonesList = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\PhonesNumbersFile.csv`, 'utf8'); //<= This came one below the other like '+549XXXXXXXXX\n+549XXXXXXXXX\n+549XXXXXXXXX'
let phonesNumbersSplited = csvFormatPhonesList.split('\n');

const channelsFound = [];
const numbersOfFilesChannels = 654; //I have 654 txt. Each file have 100 jsons

for(let i=0; i<numbersOfFilesChannels; i++) {
    let getOneSingleFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\Channels\\channels${i}.txt`, 'utf8'));

    phonesNumbersSplited.forEach((phone) => {

        getOneSingleFile.channels.forEach((channel) => {

            if (channel.friendly_name.includes(phone)){

                let parseAttributes = JSON.parse(channel.attributes);

                if (parseAttributes.long_lived == true) {
                    channelsFound.push(channel);
                }

            }

        })

    });
}

//****File of json example****//
//The array " channels " has 100 jsons inside
"channels": [
    {
    "unique_name": null,
    "members_count": 1,
    "date_updated": "2021-09-28T18:54:59Z",
    "friendly_name": "whatsapp_+549XXXXXXXXX",
    "created_by": "system",
    "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "url": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels/CHXXXXXXXX",
    "date_created": "2021-09-28T13:06:16Z",
    "sid": "CHXXXXXXXX",
    "attributes": "{\"serviceNumber\":\"whatsapp_+549XXXXXXXXX\",\"task_sid\":\"WTXXXXX\",\"from\":\"whatsapp:+549XXXXXXXXX\",\"forwarding\":true,\"proxySession\":\"KCXXXXX\",\"twilioNumber\":\"whatsapp:+549XXXXXXXXX\",\"channel_type\":\"whatsapp\",\"status\":\"INACTIVE\",\"long_lived\":true}",
    "service_sid": "ISXXXXX",
    "type": "private",
    "messages_count": 1,
    "links": {
        "webhooks": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels/CHXXXXXXXX/Webhooks",
        "messages": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels/CHXXXXXXXX/Messages",
        "invites": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels/CHXXXXXXXX/Invites",
        "members": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels/CHXXXXXXXX/Members",
        "last_message": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels/CHXXXXXXXX/Messages/IMXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    }
],
"meta": {
"page": 0,
"page_size": 100,
"first_page_url": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels?PageSize=100&Page=0",
"previous_page_url": null,
"url": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels?PageSize=100&Page=0",
"next_page_url": "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXXX/Channels?PageSize=100&Page=1",
"key": "channels"
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any obvious errors here; you need to debug your code by logging not just the iterations but the actual variables, to make sure they contain what you expect them to contain.

Comment: I added two new consoles.logs one right after ```phonesNumbers.forEach((phone) => {```
to log each phoneNumber checked and another after ```channelPage.channels.forEach((channel) =>{``` to log how many channels loop (suppossed to be 100 per page) and works fine.. I mean it does every loop as is expect.

I check with my phone number which has 8 json which ones matches and works fine.
After that i check with my phone number and another 2 phones and only find 1 json for my number and nothing else

Comment: Again, there's nothing obvious wrong with your code. Unless you provide a [mre], you can only debug this yourself.

Comment: I tried to put a json example and more descriptive names.. There is no much to see in my code i think.. that's all. If there's something more that could help let me know